# Get which child was changed via DOMSubtreeModified event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I was wondering if there could be any way to detect which child triggered `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

For instance, say I have the following code excerpt:

```
...
<ul id="chatRooms" class="lst_usr" style="position: relative;>
    <li id="1234" class="chatRoom ">
        <a href="#" class="usr_talk">...</a>
        <div class="sel_group off">...</div>
    </li>
    <li id="2345" class="chatRoom ">
        <a href="#" class="usr_talk">...</a>
        <div class="sel_group off">...</div>
    </li>
    <li id="3456" class="chatRoom ">
        <a href="#" class="usr_talk">...</a>
        <div class="sel_group off">...</div>
    </li>
    <li id="4567" class="chatRoom ">
        <a href="#" class="usr_talk">...</a>
        <div class="sel_group off">...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
....
```

And in my script, I know that I can detect `<ul>`'s components getting updated via

```
$("#chatRooms").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
     alert("chatRooms modified");
});
```

However, I could not find any documents specifying ways to find out which child element of the event being bound to triggers. Is there a way to do so with `DOMSubtreeModified` event? If not, is it possible using a different event/function?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you check for `this` or `event.target`?

Comment: The DOM mutation events were deprecated years ago and aren't supported by modern browsers. Look at [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: @AdaAzad the this keyword worked! Thank you :D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh... alright I'll look into that thank you :D